# How to change color of check icon of material UI stepper?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, stepper

I have this material UI stepper.[image]

When I complete one step, this checkicon (marked with red arrow) appears to show that step has been completed. I want to change color of this "Check Icon" only. I don't want custom icons, I just need to change color of this check icon, when I complete step. How can I do so? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/s5f158?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: working on codesandbox, please share your code and problem.

Comment: This check icon still has white color in codesandbox, I need to change this white color check icon to any other color. @Jay

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code

```
<Step
  key={label}
  {...stepProps}
  sx={{
    '& .MuiStepLabel-root .Mui-active .MuiStepIcon-text': {
      fill: 'black',
  },
}}>
  <StepLabel {...labelProps}>{label}</StepLabel>
</Step>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change color of the checkmark:

```
              <StepLabel
                StepIconProps={{
                  sx: {
                    "&.Mui-completed": {
                      background: "black",
                      borderRadius: "24px"
                    }
                  }
                }}
                {...labelProps}
              >
                {label}
              </StepLabel>
```

It's unclear from the question if you want to change the color of the circle, of the color of the checkmark inside the circle.

Change color of the circle:

```
              <StepLabel
                StepIconProps={{
                  sx: {
                    "&.Mui-completed": {
                      color:"red"
                    }
                  }
                }}
                {...labelProps}
              >
                {label}
              </StepLabel>
```